# Check on pure JS if file exists when .htaccess redirects to index.php

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, xmlhttprequest

I created my own small CMS on PHP so in my `.htaccess` I use a redirect to `index.php` like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Now with pure JavaScript I need to check if some HTML-file exists on my server so I tried to use

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', 'http://path/to/myfile.html', false);
http.send();
console.log(http.status);
```

but I get the 200 status always regardless of the file exists or doesn't

As I see  the reason is the redirect to `index.php` in my `.htaccess`

So how can I get the correct status of file existing?

Comment: With `XMLHttpRequest` it DOES can, I get the correct `http.status` if I disable the redirect in my `.htaccess`

Comment: No JS still doesn't check stuff on server. `XMLHttpRequest` just sends an AJAX request to server and there is some server code that checks it and returns response back to JS

Comment: It's enough for me to check `if(http.status == 200)` or 404

Comment: Since your JS code is using `HEAD` method, you can skip your .htaccess rule for `HEAD` requests.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this here, because my first thougt is, that it's none of the buisness of the frontend to check wether some file exists in the backend. Especially not with a dynamic backend that handles all requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Javascript code is using `HEAD` method, you can skip your .htaccess rule for all the `HEAD` requests:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !HEAD
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !HEAD` will skip your front controller rule if request method is `HEAD`.